# Convert key value pair from one single keys array with different arrays of values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to convert key value pair of json to use in ejs table iterate.

I converted key value pairs as each key - value as object which is not iterable.

Here data.metaData are keys and data.rows are values to map.

```
var data = {
    metaData: [{
            name: "SCHEDULED_TIME"
        },
        {
            name: "TRIGGER_TIME"
        },
        {
            name: "START_TIME"
        },
        {
            name: "END_TIME"
        },
        {
            name: "CEC_ID"
        },
        {
            name: "TRIGGER_TYPE"
        },
        {
            name: "STATUS"
        },
        {
            name: "JOB_NAME"
        },
    ],
    rows: [
        [
            "12:20",
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            "CLARITY_ETL",
        ],
        [
            "15:50",
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            "CLARITY_ETL",
        ],
        [
            "18:30",
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            "BUDGET_ETL",
        ],
    ]
}


**
Expected result as: **

data = [{
    "SCHEDULED_TIME": "12:20",
    "TRIGGER_TIME": null,
    "START_TIME": null,
    "END_TIME": null,
    "CEC_ID": null,
    "TRIGGER_TYPE": null,
    "STATUS": null,
    "JOB_NAME": "CLARITY_ETL",
}, {
    "SCHEDULED_TIME": "15:50",
    "TRIGGER_TIME": null,
    "START_TIME": null,
    "END_TIME": null,
    "CEC_ID": null,
    "TRIGGER_TYPE": null,
    "STATUS": null,
    "JOB_NAME": "CLARITY_ETL",
}, {
    "SCHEDULED_TIME": "18:30",
    "TRIGGER_TIME": null,
    "START_TIME": null,
    "END_TIME": null,
    "CEC_ID": null,
    "TRIGGER_TYPE": null,
    "STATUS": null,
    "JOB_NAME": "BUDGET_ETL",
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the `rows`, to map each `row` to an `object`, the `keys` of the generated `object` will come from the `metaData`:

```js
var data = {
  metaData: [
    {name: "SCHEDULED_TIME"},
    {name: "TRIGGER_TIME"},
    {name: "START_TIME"},
    {name: "END_TIME"},
    {name: "CEC_ID"},
    {name: "TRIGGER_TYPE"},
    {name: "STATUS"},
    {name: "JOB_NAME"}
  ],
  rows: [
    ["12:20", null, null, null, null, null, null, "CLARITY_ETL"],
    ["15:50", null, null, null, null, null, null, "CLARITY_ETL"],
    ["18:30", null, null, null, null, null, null, "BUDGET_ETL"]
  ]
};

let res = data.rows.map((row) =>
{
    let obj = {};
    row.forEach((val, idx) => obj[data.metaData[idx].name] = val);
    return obj;
});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Or, in a simplified version if you use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) too.

```js
var data = {
  metaData: [
    {name: "SCHEDULED_TIME"},
    {name: "TRIGGER_TIME"},
    {name: "START_TIME"},
    {name: "END_TIME"},
    {name: "CEC_ID"},
    {name: "TRIGGER_TYPE"},
    {name: "STATUS"},
    {name: "JOB_NAME"}
  ],
  rows: [
    ["12:20", null, null, null, null, null, null, "CLARITY_ETL"],
    ["15:50", null, null, null, null, null, null, "CLARITY_ETL"],
    ["18:30", null, null, null, null, null, null, "BUDGET_ETL"]
  ]
};

let res = data.rows.map(
  row => row.reduce((o, v, i) => ({...o, [data.metaData[i].name]: v}), {})
);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: @kanaka You are welcome, please consider to accept the answer if it helps you.